# Time remapping incompatible with particle info node?

Tags: materials, node-editor, particles, timeline

I'm trying to make a spark material that fades to transparent as it reaches its lifetime limit. I've succeeded, but it absolutely does not work with time remapping for some reason. Here is my problem in video form:

http://sendvid.com/ajm6afu8

I multiply the lifetime by a factor of 12 in the node editor to keep it consistent with the time remapping (because the Particle Info node's lifetime output apparently doesn't scale with time remapping, but Age does), but the second the first particle hits its lifetime limit and disappears, every single particle fades at the same time. I don't know what to do and it's driving me crazy, because I need this to work for a more complex scene that I'm nearly done with. Does anyone know a way to fix this while still using time remapping?

Comment: Yeah, this is extremely unfortunate that the Particle Info node seems to not work with built-in time remapping. Not sure about the Time Remapping addon, but it unfortunately was not usable for rendering an animation with per-frame render time in excess of 1m 30s. Did you  ever find a solution to this?

Comment: This bug is known and unresolved https://developer.blender.org/T77307